# kafka producer failing to send to topic having kerberos security when run in java 1.6 version and is working fine with 1.7

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to write to a kafka topic in a hadoop environment with kerberos security from java producer code. My code is working fine with `java version 1.7` but failing when I tried with `java 1.6`.

For `java 1.7` I used `kafka 2.10.0.9.*.jar` and for `java 1.6` I tried using `kafka 2.10.0.8.2.*.jar`.

The error is:

```
Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 8 for topics [Set(Topic1)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(0,tbldakf01adv-hdp.tdc.vzwcorp.com,6667)] failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

I have setup the jaas and conf files and from jaas im pointing to keytab file.

How do I send to a kafka topic from java code using `java 1.6` successfully?